# Fetch data from tables in SQL and create columns on the front from several tables. How can I join SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing my SQL queries but I can't combine them all. I always get a column with a query. PM_Product table of the common table of all. How can I do the merge operation?

My SQL queries:

```
 SELECT pv.PropertyValue as [Author]
 FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductProperty as pp on p.Id=pp.ProductId
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_PropertyValue as pv on pp.ValueId=pv.Id
 WHERE p.RayonId=1 AND pv.PropertyId=69 OR pv.PropertyId=67 OR pv.PropertyId=38

 SELECT pv.PropertyValue as [Publisher]
 FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductProperty as pp on p.Id=pp.ProductId
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_PropertyValue as pv on pp.ValueId=pv.Id
 WHERE p.RayonId=1 AND pv.PropertyId=9 OR pv.PropertyId=13 OR pv.PropertyId=60 OR pv.PropertyId=73

 SELECT pv.PropertyValue as [Number of Pages]
 FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductProperty as pp on p.Id=pp.ProductId
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_PropertyValue as pv on pp.ValueId=pv.Id
 WHERE p.RayonId=1 AND pv.PropertyId=61 OR pv.PropertyId=31

SELECT dpt.RegionName as [BDR]
FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductRegion ppr on p.Id=ppr.ProductId
LEFT JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.DF_PMRegionCupboardShelfType tt ON tt.Id = ppr.RegionCupboardShelfTypeId
LEFT JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.DF_PMRegionType dpt ON tt.RegionTypeId = dpt.Id
join FAZIKI.dbo.DF_Warehouse w on w.Id=dpt.WarehouseId
WHERE w.Id=45

SELECT gc.CategoryName as [Category Name]
FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductCategory as pc on p.Id=pc.ProductId
JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.GN_Category as gc on pc.CategoryId=gc.Id
WHERE p.RayonId=1

SELECT p.SalesPrice as [Sales price], cc.CurrencyCodeName as [Currency]
FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.DF_GNCurrencyCode cc on p.SalesCurrencyCodeId=cc.Id
WHERE p.RayonId=1
```

These are join SQL queries and the table they all use in common is PM_Product. How can I combine all these queries?

Comment: you can not use SELECT * inside parentheses and then assign to the one field. You must write a query whose output is a field and you cannot put the * output in a field. The output must be a single record.    (SELECT top(1) Number 
    FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductProperty as pp
    JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_PropertyValue AS pv on pp.ValueId=pv.Id
    WHERE p.Id=pp.ProductId AND pv.PropertyId=61 OR pv.PropertyId=31) as [Number Pages]

Comment: I changed my query now, can you take a look again? Each query returns a single column and I need to write them all in one query. Can you help? @گلی

Comment: If possible, put a sample of the output you want in the form of a photo or an Excel file here so that I can set your query accordingly.

Comment: https://smallpdf.com/file#s=a436769f-abf1-4fd8-8643-bdb485f2da99 I have uploaded the xml file here Sir @گلی

Comment: Note that `AND` precedes `OR`, so `a OR b AND c` is the same as `a OR (b AND c)` but `a AND b OR c` is the same as `(a AND b) OR c`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I set the query based on the Excel file and sent it to you. Please check and if you have any questions, I am at your service.

```
SELECT TOP(1) p.SalesPrice as [Sales price], cc.CurrencyCodeName as [Currency]
, (SELECT TOP(1) pv.PropertyValue 
 FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductProperty as pp on p.Id=pp.ProductId
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_PropertyValue as pv on pp.ValueId=pv.Id
 WHERE p.RayonId=1 AND pv.PropertyId=69 OR pv.PropertyId=67 OR pv.PropertyId=38) AS [Author]
, ( SELECT TOP(1) pv.PropertyValue 
 FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductProperty as pp on p.Id=pp.ProductId
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_PropertyValue as pv on pp.ValueId=pv.Id
 WHERE p.RayonId=1 AND pv.PropertyId=9 OR pv.PropertyId=13 OR pv.PropertyId=60 OR pv.PropertyId=73) as [Publisher]
,  (SELECT TOP(1) pv.PropertyValue 
 FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductProperty as pp on p.Id=pp.ProductId
 JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_PropertyValue as pv on pp.ValueId=pv.Id
 WHERE p.RayonId=1 AND pv.PropertyId=61 OR pv.PropertyId=31) as [Number of Pages]
, (SELECT TOP(1) dpt.RegionName 
FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductRegion ppr on p.Id=ppr.ProductId
LEFT JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.DF_PMRegionCupboardShelfType tt ON tt.Id = ppr.RegionCupboardShelfTypeId
LEFT JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.DF_PMRegionType dpt ON tt.RegionTypeId = dpt.Id
join FAZIKI.dbo.DF_Warehouse w on w.Id=dpt.WarehouseId WHERE w.Id=45) AS [BDR]
, (SELECT TOP(1) gc.CategoryName 
FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductCategory as pc on p.Id=pc.ProductId
JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.GN_Category as gc on pc.CategoryId=gc.Id
WHERE p.RayonId=1) as [Category Name]
FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product as p
JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.DF_GNCurrencyCode cc on p.SalesCurrencyCodeId=cc.Id
WHERE p.RayonId=1
```